# Easy introduction to Heckscher-Ohlin model

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for an easy introduction to this model. I have no background in economics at all. A bit of math is ok. I would prefer books, but pdfs are also ok. I searched after a few books, but I think many are too advanced for me (having no background in economics).

Comment: Hi: I know zero about the model but this seems reasonable possibly. https://www.princeton.edu/~ies/IES_Studies/S77.pdf